# Html and CSS , Issue with adding text to cube's surfaces and displacing its shadow and itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100px;
}

body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  perspective: 20em;
  perspective-origin: 77px 100px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  background: aqua;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  transform: translateZ(-130px) rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(3deg);
  bottom: 0em;
  left: 4em;
  box-shadow: 0 120px 100px 10px blue, 50px 120px 200px 10px blue;
  filter: blur(100px);
}

.top,
.bottom,
.left,
.right,
.front,
.back {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px blue inset, 0 0 0 2em aqua inset;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-1em);
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(90deg);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-1em) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="top"> </div>
    <div class="bottom"> </div>
    <div class="left"> </div>
    <div class="right"> </div>
    <div class="front"> </div>
    <div class="back"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow">
  </div>
</body>
```

The Problems:

1. I want to add different texts to the surfaces (1st,2st,3st,4st) of the cube (welcome) (to) (main) (page)
2. In addition, the shadow under the cube is not centered. How can I center it?
3. Finally, I couldn't move the Cube to a higher position either.
   How can I solve these problems?

The visual is below:
[image]

Comment: Check my answer, I believe I completed all your points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "move" the cube, your div should have proportions. I inserted `width: 2em;` and `height: calc(2em + 20px);` on your cube. I added 20px on height due to shadow, you might want to show that it "hovers".

To center the shadow, you need to use `left: 50%;` as well as add first in `transform` `translateX(-50%)`. This will keep it centralized on X axis no matter the screen size and since you use `flex`, it would be good to go all-together. To make it responsive from bottom, I used `bottom: calc(50% - 2em - 20px);` (2em is the height of your cube and 20px the float).

For the text, wrap it inside a `<span>`, then center it with CSS and use `transform: rotateY(180deg);` to flip the text of the inverted `divs`. I also reversed the rotation animation to follow the pattern you want.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100px;
}

body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  perspective: 20em;
  perspective-origin: 77px 100px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
  height: calc(2em + 20px);
  width: 2em;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  background: aqua;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(-130px) rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(3deg);
  bottom: calc(50% - 2em - 20px);
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 120px 100px 10px blue, 50px 120px 200px 10px blue;
  filter: blur(100px);
}

.top,
.bottom,
.left,
.right,
.front,
.back {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px blue inset, 0 0 0 2em aqua inset;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-1em);
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(90deg);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-1em) rotateY(90deg);
}

.right>span,
.front>span,
.left>span,
.back>span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}

.left>span,
.back>span {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="top"> </div>
    <div class="bottom"> </div>
    <div class="left">
      <span>page</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span>to</span>
    </div>
    <div class="front">
      <span>welcome</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>main</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow">
  </div>
</body>
```